# How can i create circle chart?

Tags: html, css, charts

First of all tell me whats this, this is input type val or div or what? then how can I create One of them?

[image]

Comment: I guess the above was made through SVG. Try this: [Demo](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html) Look at the chart at the right middle area. It was built using http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a `canvas` html element and some javascript. have a look at 
[chartjs.org](http://www.chartjs.org)
it's really simple to make Doughnut Charts whith this library
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart
here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4vo72rLd/1/

Comment: Thank you . Is It method to I write this chart ? I  really hate to use plugins.

Comment: @user3881935 yes, technically you can. Canvas has several methods for drawing paths, boxes, circles, text, and adding images. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly called as 'Donut Chart'. It is constructed using SVG and javascript D3.js

You can refer to this

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193

Also, there is a wonderful tutorial available on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thank you , But I don't use plugin I need to create this

Comment: You can try using this project for reference.
[Open Order Framework](https://github.com/lbacaj/OpenOrderFramework)
It has used donut chart for analytics. Good Luck!